# NextJS Vercel deployment error: "The path you are accessing was not found in the Build Outputs of your Deployment."

Tags: next.js, deployment, http-status-code-404, vercel, custom-error-pages

I am very new to nextJS. I am trying to deploy a build of an app I'm building so I can show it to friends. (a simple pokemon team generator app)

It compiles fine when I run `$npm run build`, and when I am developing the app and previewing it via `$npm run dev`, it works just fine in localhost:3000.

However, when I try to deploy to Vercel, I instead get a 404 error, and Vercel's description of the error says **"The path you are accessing was not found in the Build Outputs of your Deployment."**

I tried moving my api folder with all my data to public to see if that would fix the issue, but it didn't work. The truth is I'm very new to nextJS and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is a link to my repo. I suspect it is probably something wrong with a config or my directory structure, but I'm honestly not sure where to even begin troubleshooting. Any hints/help would be appreciated.

[Github Repo Link](https://github.com/manski117/pokemon-random-team-generator)
[The Vercel deployment link that doesn't work](https://pokemon-random-team-generator-w113-jgcgikx0o-manski117.vercel.app/)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem, hopefully this can help someone else in the future.

First: I set up my project weird. I made a repo in github and cloned it, but then made my app *within that repo folder* using create-t3-app. So my .next folder was not in my root directory.

**Fixed by doing 2 things:**

1. Changed the root directory in Vercel -> Settings -> General to actually be the name of my folder that create-t3-app created.
2. Also in Vercel Settings General, I went changed the framework preset to Next.js.

Hope this helps, person in the future!